# What is the best way to make many versions ((Or history)) of Table's rows

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, logging

> *Hi everyone,*
>
> I'm trying to make my application
>   support Logging but I'm very new at
>   this approach.
>
> - I were going to add new tables to my database for each table that i want
>     to support logging to it and then deal
>     wit that by my DAL "EF in my
>     approach". But this will make me add a
>     lot of work to both DB and DAL.
> - **So i wonder if there is an easier    way to do this ??** I don't know maybe
>     something like "Log Provider" or SQL
>     Server Triggers or something ??
>
> **please support me with your advices even in general ideas about support
>   logging.**
>
> ...

***Edit1:***

For example suppose that I've "Persons" table and "Person" Model i want to support logging to my person table **so i want to know when and what happened to some person data at specific time**. I hope the point is clear !.

.

***Edit2:***

Sorry for my blind and not clear question but i just realize that the **Triggers is just the best way to do what i want to do**.

sorry again ;}

Comment: Sorry my question wasn't so clear and i can't determine which answer should be the right :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC application. This provides the ability to add [custom filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410209%28VS.90%29.aspx) to action methods. These are attribute classes inheriting from `System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute`.

I simply decorate any action method I wish to log (or the controller class for all methods) with something like '[Log(LogLevel.High)]'. The `LogAttribute` class which provides this has a dependancy on my interface `ILoggingProvider` which contains a `Write` method (the concrete implementation logs to database). I handle the `OnActionExecuted` event in the `LogAttribute` class and use the eventargs to construct the data to pass to the `Write` method. If you wanted to log results too you could also log the `OnResultExecuted` event.

Answer (score 0):

The one that comes in mind now is using interception (for example using Unity to intercept instances or types).

I've used this a while ago for trying to fail back to local data (cached from previous requests) when wcf services failed.

So I guess you could intercept calls to your DAL classes and try to log the information in the pre/post events of the pipeline.

For more info you can check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660890%28v=PandP.20%29.aspx).

Another approach could be to inject a logger class in your DAL classes (which hopefully have a base DAL class) by using an IoC container (Unity again, or MEF if you're in .NET 4.0).

If something else crosses my mind I`ll let you know.

Regards...

Answer (score 0):

**I saw many examples that use "Triggers" to make sort of "History" for a table.**

And they made Triggers for "Insert, Update and Delete" to just that tables that they want.

I consider that is very nice especially it doesn't need any interposing from my application.

**But i still afraid from Triggers to effect performance !!!**

So what is your Advice ??